# why does realloc throws me "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"

Tags: c

I am really new to C and this is for a school assignment.
So, I am tasked to transpose a given matrix.

My current function is the following:

```
void matrixTranspose(int rows, int cols, int **array) {
    int temp[rows][cols];
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            temp[i][j] = array[i][j];
        }
    }

    array = realloc(array, cols * sizeof(int *));

    for (i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
        array[i] = realloc(array[i], rows * sizeof(int));
    }

    for (i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
            array[i][j] = temp[j][i];
        }
    }
 }
```

If I introduce equal values for columns and rows or if the value of rows is **bigger** than the value of columns it works fine, but for some reason when the value of rows is **smaller** than the value of columns, it does not works. (Throws me "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" error).

My main looks like this:

```
int main() {
    int **mat;
    int cols, rows;
    int i, j;

   printf("Enter number of rows\n");
    scanf("%d", &rows);
    printf("Enter number of columns\n");
    scanf("%d", &cols);

   mat = (int **) malloc (sizeof(int *) * rows);

   for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
       mat[i] = (int *) malloc (sizeof(int) * cols);
   }

   for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
       for(j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
           mat[i][j] = rand() % 10;
       }
   }

   printf("\nBefore transpose: \n");
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
       for(j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
           printf("%d ", mat[i][j]);
       }
       printf("\n");
   }

   matrixTranspose(rows, cols, mat);
   printf("\nAfter transpose: \n");

   for (i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
       for(j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
           printf("%d ", mat[i][j]);
      }
       printf("\n");
   }

 }
```

I hope I explained myselft correctly, sorry for my english, it is not my first language. Thanks

Comment: `array` is pass by value, so you won't get the new allocation on return of `matrixTranspose`.

Comment: You assume `realloc` will always succeed. If `realloc` fails, it returns `NULL`, but it does not free the passed in memory either. So your call would leak the original allocation.

Comment: If you `realloc` the `array` to have fewer number of rows, then the previously excess rows have been leaked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you modify `array` in `matrixTranspose`, you're changing a local variable.  That change isn't visible in the calling function, so `mat` in `main` no longer points to valid memory.

You need to change the function to accept address of a `int **` and dereference it as needed.

```
void matrixTranspose(int rows, int cols, int ***array) {
    int temp[rows][cols];
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            temp[i][j] = (*array)[i][j];
        }
    }

    *array = realloc(*array, cols * sizeof(int *));
    if (!*array) {
        perror("realloc failed");
        exit(1);
    }

    int min = rows < cols ? rows : cols;
    for (i = 0; i < min; i++) {
        (*array)[i] = realloc((*array)[i], rows * sizeof(int));
        if (!(*array)[i]) {
            perror("realloc failed");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    if (rows > cols) {
        for (i = min; i < rows; i++) {
            free((*array)[i]);
        }
    } else if (cols > rows) {
        for (i = min; i < cols; i++) {
            (*array)[i] = malloc(rows * sizeof(int));
            if (!(*array)[i]) {
                perror("malloc failed");
                exit(1);
            }
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
            (*array)[i][j] = temp[j][i];
        }
    }
 }
```

Note that if the number of rows and columns are not the same, you'll need to either `free` the extra rows you no longer have or use `malloc` to allocate new rows.

Note also that you should be checking the return value of `malloc` and `realloc` for failure.

Then pass the address of `mat` to this function:

```
matrixTranspose(rows, cols, &mat);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the transpose function like this:

```
int ** matrixTranspose(int rows, int cols, int **array) {
    ...
    return array;
}
```

And then in `main` call it like this:

```
mat = matrixTranspose(rows, cols, mat);
```

Apart from that, I recommend these thanges. I have changed the argument to `sizeof` to be the actual variable instead of the type.

```
array = realloc(array, cols * sizeof(*array));

for (i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
    array[i] = realloc(array[i], rows * sizeof(*array[0]));
}
```

and

```
mat = (int **) malloc (sizeof(*mat) * rows);

for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    mat[i] = (int *) malloc (sizeof(*mat[0]) * cols);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your array is passed by value (i.e. you don't pass a pointer to your matrix). Yet you change it.

> ```
> array = realloc(array, cols * sizeof(int *));
> ```

This is just a local change. Also,

> ```
> for (i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
>        array[i] = realloc(array[i], rows * sizeof(int));
> }
> ```

If `rows < col` this piece of code will try to reallocate memory for `array[i]` where `i>rows-1`. That implies deallocating the memory pointed to by `array[i]` has never been allocated and you have no idea where it points to.

Answer (score 0):

> I am tasked to transpose a given matrix.

Key problem: Code passed the pointer by value and `matrixTranspose()` need to receive its address in order to modify it.  Well answered by others without changing much.

---

Yet consider a larger change instead.  Do not modify the original matrix, make a transposed copy and free matrix  helper functions.

```
int **matrixTranspose_copy(int rows, int cols, const int **array) {
  int **transpose = malloc(sizeof *transpose * cols);
  for (int r = 0; r < cols; r++) {
    transpose[r] = malloc(sizeof *transpose[r] * rows);
    for(int c = 0; c < rows; c++) {
      transpose[r][c] = array[c][r];
      }
    }
  }
  return transpose;
}

void matrixFree(int rows, const int **array) {
  for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
    free(array[r]);
    }
  free(array);
}

void matrixTranspose_inplace(int rows, int cols, int ***array) {
  int **original = *array;
  *array = matrixTranspose_copy(rows, cols, original);
  matrixFree(original);
}
```